# Executing .cmd file on remote server with parameter from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a .cmd file on a remote server with a variable but I am having issues with passing the variable which is causing the below error message:

> The term 'D:\MyDir\MyFile.cmd myparam' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name,  or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

This error only occurs when I attempt to execute the .cmd with a variable / parameter.

Here is my code-

```
param($InParam)
$Username = 'MYMACHINE\myuser'
$Password = 'mypassword'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
If ($InParam -eq "test")
{
$Script = {&"D:\MyDir\MyFile.cmd myparam"}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MY-PC-NAME -Authentication Default -ScriptBlock $Script -Credential $Cred
```

Any help hugely appreciated and TIA!

Comment: The parameter `-ArgumentList` of `Invoke-Command` might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is it's looking for the file "MyFile.cmd myparam" which doesn't exist. You need to move your quotes so that the param is in a separate string:

```
$Script = {&"D:\MyDir\MyFile.cmd" myparam}
```

Comment: So simple yet this has been troubling me for hours! Thank you